# How to calculate the number of column values got changed by comparing two dataframes with same columns in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to compare two data frames and  get the count of number of columns that are changed from first dataframe to second dataframe based on joining key using spark.

```
df1
id val1  val2  val3  val4
1   a    b    c    d
2   d    f    k    e
4   r    t    y    u

df2
id val1 val2 val3 val4
1   a    h    c    l
2   d    f    k    e
4   g    a    w    u

count:
id  count
1    2
2    0
4    3
```

Comment: Have you, by any luck, tried anything ? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

#change aliases to avoid duplicate columns in joined dataframe
df2=df2.select(*(col(x).alias('d2'+x) for x in df2.columns))

joineddf=df1.alias('df1').join(df2.alias('df2'), df1.id == df2.d2id) 
col = [z for z in df1.columns]
jd=joineddf.rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id,sum([int( not x) for x in [row[y]==row['d2'+y] for y in col ]])))

spark.createDataFrame(jd, ['id', 'count']).show()  
Output:
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    2|
|  2|    0|
|  4|    3|
+---+-----+
```

i have taken  all the columns in sum including  'id' field as the resulting 0 would not add to the sum.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If there are huge number of columns in each data frame, what do we need to do.the above one is again a sql query. Do we have any solution using dataframes or RDD's in spark.